# A free WebDAV client for Windows?

Tags: windows, sharepoint, ftp, webdav, wss-3.0

I'd like to copy files from a network drive to a SharePoint site (perhaps as a mapped drive).  What's a good client to do so?  Obviously Windows (XP) Explorer is bad, I'm trying RichCopy at the moment.  Any opinions on CoreFTP?  Are there any recommended open-source WebDAV clients?

Comment: Why is it bad?  What am I missing out on?

Comment: +1 to MrChrister, I don't know why the webdav client that is built into Windows won't be good for you.

Comment: It's bad because it doesn't offer verbose error messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use http://www.anyclient.com/ for all my WebDav transactions and have had no issues...

Comment: AnyClient does look pretty good.  I had trouble though using my system proxy to connect to our Intranet SharePoint.  I ended up connecting to the SharePoint document library as a mapped network drive, then migrating all of my files / folders using FreeFileSync (http://sourceforge.net/projects/freefilesync/) which worked fantastically and produced verbose errors for all of issues with files that cannot be uploaded to SharePoint.  Thanks for the answer Jesse!

Answer (score 4):

Bitkinex works great. (http://www.bitkinex.com)

And for mapping WebDAV as a drive you can use the free client from http://www.cloudsafe.com 
(https://secure.cloudsafe.com/pages/topics_cloudsafeclient.html)

Comment: Cheers for the added comment on this - seems like it was a great question :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried WinSCP or http://www.bitkinex.com/

What about wget?

Incidentally, what's wrong with Explorer?

Answer (score 1):

I used freefilesync to sync my remote folder to the sharepoint folder. I do this using the batch file utility that comes with freefilesync, then I call the batchfile using FreeFileSync.exe @batchfile@.  It works fine, except that it remains as checked out, so users still cannot see it.  How do I change the status to checked-in programmatically?

Comment: @gary - Not sure how much this helps (way back when) I was on the project that required the WebDAV file management, I did try AnyClient at first and it was pretty good.  FreeFileSync proved better for my application though - I guess I never noticed this answer though! (I wrapped the project in June '10).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at http://www.ajaxfilebrowser.com/. It is a WebDAV client built using pure JavaScript that runs in IE, Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

You can use it for free from this web page, even no installation is required: http://www.ajaxfilebrowser.com/?CrossDomainDemo

Answer (score 0):

Cyberduck https://cyberduck.io/download/ is free and has source code available: https://trac.cyberduck.io/wiki/WikiStart#Source

And WindowsExplorer is bad because it has a path length limitation.